# How to install or set up Ext JS 5 or 6 in Eclipse Luna or Juno... Need detailed process to make Ext JS work

Tags: eclipse, extjs5, eclipse-juno, eclipse-luna, extjs6

I have found a video link with Ext JS 4 set up. But I also found two different videos on youtube... One explained with help of pre installed XAMPP and the other video using spket IDE plugin. So Iam bit confused. Whats the difference? Can I use Ext JS without installing XAMPP ( I already have tomcat server integrated with my Eclipse ). Please help me with step by step process to set up Ext JS 5 or 6 on my eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Even I recently started with extjs 5 and 6, it was a bit of a pain to understand the complete folder structure but Its not that though.

Yes you can use it with a pre-installed Apache Tomcat.
Create a normal dynamic web project, in its WebContent folder add the required extjs dependencies(ex. ext-all.js, etc) 
Although i would suggest you to maintain the heirarchy while copying the dependencies.

And now all remains is for you to create a html or jsp file and start coding and giving the proper path for your dependencies.

Comment: you can download the extjs 5 from the [sencha](https://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/evaluate/)  website or from [here](http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/extjs/5.1.0)

the possible problem you would face would be in finding the dependencies file. To solve that search the file names only in the **build** folder

Answer (score 0):

The two videos you mentioned seem to address two compeltely different issues.
You need a server application to run your ExtJs applications properly, and you need IDE integration to be able to use Inellisense/Autocomplete while writing code in your IDE.

You need both: 
1) Use your tomcat server to run the application.
2) Spket is the best option for Eclipse Integration I ever used.I I highly recommend it.